# Why do I have to call this.cdRef.detectChanges() when a form control validator changes to avoid expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror?

Tags: angular

Mine is not a problem but a question.
I have a method to change Validators in a FormGroup and, if i remove `cdRef.detectChanges()`, I get an error message like this:

> expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror.

This method is called in a (change) event of a `<select>` `html` element.

I have this code

```
constructor(
    private service: LoaderFreeService,
    private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ){}
....

 setRequiredOffice() {
    if (this.loaderFreeModalForm.get("startingScope").value === "ROLE") {
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      this.loaderFreeModalForm
        .get("startingOfficeName")
        .setValidators(Validators.required);
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    } else {
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      this.loaderFreeModalForm.get("startingOfficeName").clearValidators();
      this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

EDIT: i've also tried with `this.loaderFreeModalForm.updateValueAndValidity()`, but it still shows me this error.

Comment: Did you try to use `updateValueAndValidity` method from FormGroup instead of CDR?
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#updateValueAndValidity

Comment: Yes, it still shows me this error

Comment: have you defined onPush strategy or the default one

Comment: the default one

Comment: Could u show more source code from component? I think you are changing FormControl too early, but to investigate it I need to check how your component looks like.

Comment: I initialize the form on init. the problem was the fact that it was triggering the wrong way in a <select> (change) method.